# Is there a better way to repeat a symbol inside a printw-routine 'n' times? (C++/NCurses)

Tags: c++, repeat, ncurses

I am currently quite a newbie with C++ and NCurses and I have ran into a situation where I need to repeat a certain symbol *n* times during a *printw* (or to be more specific, a *mvwprintw*), depending the value of a certain variable.

This is my current working solution, but I'm wondering if there's a better and less messy looking way to do this:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int n = 8;
    std::string repeat = std::string(n, '.');

    // ncurses initialization
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();

    // creating a window
    WINDOW *bottombar = newwin(3, 118, 22, 1);
    refresh();

    //printing inside the window, repeating the '.' symbol n times.
    mvwprintw(bottombar, 1, 1, "%s", repeat.c_str());
    wrefresh(bottombar);

    // waiting for user input to close program
    getch(); 
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is eight periods inside the specified window, as expected.

Comment: IMHO the shown solution is very good.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to hear! I guess there's no better way then. This just feels a bit complicated way to repeat a char compared to some other languages :)